# How to join Maps

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

How to join `newMap` detals in `custMap`.

```
 Map<String, Customer> custMap= new HashMap<String,Customer>();   
 Map<String, DoCustomer> newMap= new HashMap<String,DoCustomer>();
     for (Map.Entry<String, DoCustomer> cust: newMap.entrySet()) {   
     custMap.put(cust.getKey(),cust.getValue()); 
 }

public class DoCustomer {
private Long id;

private String custName;

private String description;
    private String status;
    private List<DoCustomerBranch> doCustomerBranch=new ArrayList<DoCustomerBranch>
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getCustName() {
    return custName;
}
public void setCustName(String custName) {
    this.custName = custName;
}
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}
public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}
getter/setters of doCustomerBranch
}

  @Entity
  @Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
  public class Customer implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Long id;

private String custName;

private String description;

private String createdBy;
private Date createdOn;

private String updatedBy;
private Date updatedOn;


private Set<CustomerBranch> customerBranch=new HashSet<CustomerBranch>



@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "CUSTOMER_SEQ")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "CUSTOMER_SEQ", sequenceName = "CUSTOMERN_SEQ",   allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name = "ID")
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}


@Column(name = "CUST_NAME",nullable=false)
public String getCustName() {
    return custName;
}

public void setCustName(String custName) {
    this.custName = custName;
}

@Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}


@Column(name = "CREATED_BY", length = 50)
public String getCreatedBy() {
    return createdBy;
}

public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
    this.createdBy = createdBy;
}

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "CREATED_ON")
public Date getCreatedOn() {
    return createdOn;
}

public void setCreatedOn(Date createdOn) {
    this.createdOn = createdOn;
}

@Column(name = "UPDATED_BY", length = 50)
public String getUpdatedBy() {
    return updatedBy;
}

public void setUpdatedBy(String updatedBy) {
    this.updatedBy = updatedBy;
}

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "UPDATED_ON")
public Date getUpdatedOn() {
    return updatedOn;
}

public void setUpdatedOn(Date updatedOn) {
    this.updatedOn = updatedOn;
}
    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE }, fetch =         FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "customer")
public Set<CustomerBranch> getCustomerBranch() {
    return customerBranch;
}


public void setCustomerBranch(Set<CustomerBranch> customerBranch) {
    this.customerBranch = customerBranch;
}

 }
```

CustomerBranch

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER_BRANCH")
public class CustomerBranch implements Serializable{

   @Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "CUSTOMER_BRANCH_SEQ")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "CUSTOMER_BRANCH_SEQ", sequenceName =   "CUSTOMER_BRANCH_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;
private String branchName;

private String branchAddress;

private Customer customer;



public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "BRANCH_NAME",nullable=false)
public String getBranchName() {
    return branchName;
}



@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "MOBEE_CUSTOMER")
public Customer getCustomer() {
    return customer;
}

public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
    this.customer = customer;
}

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `join`? And what's wrong with your sample code? Does it do what you want?

Comment: i want to migrate newMap values into custMap.i am getting error is  The method put(String, Customer) in the type Map<String,Customer> is not applicable 
 for the arguments (String,  DoCustomer)

Comment: Can you please post the definitions of Customer and DoCustomer classes?

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your code is that you want to put a `DoCustomer` in a `Customer` container. It only works if `DoCustomer` is a subclass of `Customer`.

Edit 1: You could use `BeanUtils` to convert a `DoCustomer` into a `Customer`. [Here](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-copy-properties-from-one-bean-to-another.html) is a good tutorial.

Comment: Thank you ,DoCustomer is not Subclass of Customer ,In this example Customer is Entity and DoCustomer is propertys of Customer ,can u please tell me another way for this sol,Is it possible using BeanUtils.....

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean:

```
custMap.putAll(newMap)
```

Comment: ya I want this sol but iam getting error is The method put(String, Customer) in the type Map<String,Customer> is not applicable 
 for the arguments (String,  DoCustomer)

Comment: from the name of class `DoCustomer` I have supposed that it is a subclass of `Customer` class, but I did a mistake. So method that is proposed by me is not correct for your situation

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else has pointed out, we need to know what DoCustomer is to be able to help.

But, from what you have given us, I'd suggest casting each DoCustomer to a Customer or, more correctly, making a new Customer from the fields of each DoCustomer.

Something like:

```
custMap.put(cust.getKey(), new Customer(cust.getValue().getId(), cust.getValue().getCustName(), and so on..));
```

inside your for loop.

I can see the customer class defined you have provided doesn't have a constructor, so naturally you would have to add one to it

Comment: thank you Michael you are write but in my customer entity is mapping by CustomerBranch in that time I was i have pblm with costructor

Comment: Are you referring to Set<CustomerBranch> customerBranch? Is this the same field as List<DoCustomerBranch> doCustomerBranch in DoCustomer? I can understand that converting between the two would make this a very long-winded solution.

Comment: custBranchesList  is the list type of List<CustomerBranch> and custBrancheChangesList  is the list type of List<DoCustomeBranch> can it possible to join  custBranchesList.add(custBrancheChangesList ) ...?

Comment: It's the same problem as your original question; you can only do so if you're willing to convert them from DoCustomerBranch to CustomerBranch using the same technique.